# Has Many Through where the middle table has both forain keys in laravel 5.6

Tags: has-many-through, eloquent, belongs-to, laravel-5.6

I need to make a HasManyThough relation where the middle Model holds the foreign keys of both Models.
Here is detail:

Migrations:

```
    Schema::create('carriers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
    });

    Schema::create('shipping_zones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
    });

    Schema::create('shipping_rates', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('shipping_zone_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('carrier_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->decimal('rate', 20, 6);
    });
```

Now I need something like

```
$carrier->shippingZone()
```

Is there any easy way to get this?

Answer (score 1):

As per your migrations you need **Many To Many** relation rather than the **HasManyThough** relation.

Carrier.php

```
public function shippingZones()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ShippingZone', 'shipping_rates);
    }
```

You can access all shipping zones related to the carrier using, `$carrier->shippingZones`.

If you need to chain the query you can use `$shippingZones = $carrier->shippingZones()->orderBy('id')->get();` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

If you need to use `HasManyThough` you would have to change the migrations. [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)